# What is the difference between a historical drama and a period drama?

Tags: terminology, genre, drama

I've been under the impression that a historical drama is non-fiction whereas a period drama is fiction.

Comment: There probably is none - they seem to be interchangeable - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_period_drama

Answer (score 44, accepted):

"Drama" is usually meant to indicate fiction.

I've generally understood historical/period drama as:

- **Historical drama** - a drama based on historical events
- **Period drama** - a drama based in a particular time or period, not obviously based on real events

So, [The Crown](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4786824/) would be a *historical* drama

> Follows the political rivalries and romance of Queen Elizabeth II's reign and the events that shaped the second half of the 20th century.

and [Downton Abbey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1606375/) would be a *period* drama

> A chronicle of the lives of the British aristocratic Crawley family and their servants in the early 20th Century.

(the Crawleys being a fictional family where Queen Elizabeth II obviously isn't)

However, the term is somewhat ambiguous and commentators may use them interchangeably, so don't expect my opinion to be rigidly observed by all.

I'd expect a historical non-fiction programme to be called a "historical documentary" rather than a "drama", even though the event(s) portrayed might be dramatic in nature.

Comment: That makes sense. What, then, is a "costume drama"? The same as a period drama, I think.

Comment: @HemiPoweredDrone I'd say both types could be considered costume dramas, depending on the time period. Costume drama implies a certain elaborateness of costuming, usually pre-early-20th century, IMO, but I doubt there's a firm definition.

Comment: @Wossname agreed. I did see "Mad Men" called a costume drama at least once.

Comment: This is pretty much how I understand it. I've always felt that historic dramas are about historic events, where period dramas can take place during them while not primarily *about* them (like the difference between something like Darkest Hour and something like Home Fires).

Comment: Good answer, except for the opening comment about the use of the word "drama" in this context. [Drama](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drama) can be either fictional or non-fictional. When describing films or television series as "drama," what's meant isn't that they're fiction, but that they're primarily intended seriously. Contrast with "comedy," which is primarily intended humourously.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I disagree.  As a British English speaker, a drama is necessarily fictional.

Comment: @MartinBonner - (I'm a mix, American and British -- last 20 years here in the UK.) It's usually fictional, it just doesn't *have* to be. Note that the linked Collins definition doesn't mention fiction. But horses for courses...

Comment: @Snow Would Does [The Secret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_(TV_series/)) qualify as a period drama or a historical drama? It is based on true events, but not necessarily well-known.

Comment: The drama == fiction equivalence, at least in British English, is definitely more blurry than that. For instance, Micro Men was described by the continuity announcement (in the copy I recorded at the time) as being "drama", even though it was largely based on real events (with some changes and scenes invented to help the narrative). I would personally call it a docudrama but I'm not sure if that is accurate. But drama, if it can't be non-fiction, can certainly be "semi-fiction".

Comment: @Muzer Taking the BrEng definition of "drama", this "semi-fiction" could potentially even encompass dramatised reconstructions (such as those found in real-world crime shows), though in that context it would probably be referred to as simply *drama* as opposed to *a drama*.